# Can lower redis sentinel talk to higher redis instance?

Tags: redis

When I am doing an upgrade in Redis, 
Should I always keep my sentinel version upgraded with my Redis version(3.0 redis + 3.0 redis sentinel)  to (4.0 redis + 4.0 redis sentinel)?

Will it work if 3.0 sentinel + 4.0 redis instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems not matter. redis sentinel is just a service which talk to redis.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there are no problems. Redis Sentinel acts as a client when connecting to Redis servers.